# Independent set and clique of a minimal non-strongly perfect

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A graph $G$ is strongly perfect if each of its induced subgraphs $H$ of $G$ contains an independent set which meets all the cliques (maximal complete subgraphs) in it. A graph is minimal non-strongly perfect if $G$ is not strongly perfect by every proper induced subgraph is strongly perfect.

**Question:**
*Is it true that every **maximal clique on 2 vertices** of a minimal non-strongly perfect graph is missed by an independent set that meets all the remaining maximal cliques?*

This statement is not true for maximal cliques on 3 vertices; for example, the graph $\overline{C}_{6}$ is minimal non-strongly perfect but every independent set meets all cliques of size 3.